# How do I match any non-word character at the end of a line or just the end of the line

Tags: regex

Using regex, I want to match all non-word characters at the end of a line, or, if there isn't a non-word character, just match the end of the line.

This is what I thought it should be as simple as:

```
/\W*$/
```

That is, match zero or more non-word characters, followed by the end of the line.

I tried it at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but it's not that simple.

Then, taking it one step further, I also want to match white space at the end of the line, like this:

```
/[\W\s]*$/
```

That is, match zero or more characters from the set, non-word characters and white space characters, followed by the end of the line.

Of course, this isn't working either.

At the end of the day I want to replace anything at the end of a line that is not an alphanumeric character with a full stop, using javascript.

Comment: Do you want to replace the newline character also? Because `$` does not match a newline character, it matches the position **before** `\n`. The other thing is `\s` is already included in `\W` since whitespace chars are also non word characters.

Comment: `\W*$` is correct.  Did you select multiline mode?  If you don't do that, `$` matches only at the very end of the string.

Comment: @AlanMoore I see now. I tried it in a js interpreter and it works perfectly. Also, I don't want to match the newline, and I'm not using multiline mode.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.replace` method with a direct regex, not a string.  The `^` is the "not" character.  So anything NOT a alphanumeric.

```
var good = bad.replace(/[^\w]*$/g, "");
```

Proof:

```
> bad = "asd$f   "
"asd$f   "
> bad.replace(/[^\w]*$/g, "")
"asd$f"
```

Comment: Thanks for the "direct regex" tip, I didn't know that. This answer works, except I have to remove the `g` because that replaces once for each  non word found. Eg, try `bad = "asdfa : .   "`, the output is `asdfa??`

Comment: If this is correct, please accept my answer.  The community is empowered by upvotes and accepted answers.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My first approach was correct. It was just the regex tool that wasn't playing nicely.

**Either** `/\W*$/`

**Or** `/[^\w]*$/`

Which are obviously the same.

*Tested it using [this](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/) jQuery terminal.*